# Created two Lists from same array, Modifying one List, changes the other

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

I created two list from same array and sorted one of them. When I tried to change one list, other list also got updated.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(ar);
List<Integer> sorted = Arrays.asList(ar);
Collections.sort(sorted);
list.set(0,10000000); //changes sorted also
```

It took me a while figure out, below mentioned  code worked.

`List<Integer> sorted = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ar));`

**I want to know why my first approach didn't work?** I created two separate lists, why the changes are taking place in both of them. How does java assign values to variables here?

Comment: `list` and `sorted` are pointing to the same array, aren't they?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: but he only sorts one List. I'm going to up-vote this as an interesting question.

Comment: I am a bit surprised that this seems to be the first time this question is asked on SO since the "issue" is as old as the `Arrays` api itself (java 1.2). And I doubt everyone read (and understood) the javadoc until now…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Java documentation for `Arrays.asList`:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination with `Collection.toArray()`. The returned list is serializable and implements `RandomAccess`.

So when you change something in list, it "writes through" to the underlying array, `ar`, which is also the underlying array in sorted, so the change is reflected in sorted as well.

Also, the code for `asList` is:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(a);
}
```

This is `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`, which has the following definition:

```
ArrayList(E[] array) {
    a = Objects.requireNonNull(array);
}
```

What is important is that `a` is not copied, it is the original array. The `java.util.ArrayList` class has the following constructor

```
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
     elementData = c.toArray();
     size = elementData.length;
     // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
     if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
         elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
 }
```

so in the `java.util.ArrayList` constructor, we create copies of each element, and in `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`, we do not.

Comment: Please, don’t mix up `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` and `java.util.ArrayList`. The behavior hasn’t changed in Java 8.

Comment: @Holger, thanks! I updated my original post to include this point.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays has its own implementations of ArrayList which does not make a copy of array from toList

Answer (score 1):

A List is a collection of objects, and both list are collections of the same objects. The set statement changes an object, and the object is shared by both lists.

I don't understand why the second version works.

Answer (score 0):

*list* & *sorted* are still pointing to the same memory address of *ar* in the first approach while in the second approach a new memory address has been allocated after calling a constructor a new memory block is allocated to the class object.